# Bootstrap Button Full Width for Smaller Screen Sizes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want my bootstrap buttons to take up full screen width(well, almost) for smaller screens. `btn-block` does make the button extend, but for all types of screen.

Can this `btn-block` be customized using CSS (for example using `@media`) so that it is activated only for smaller screens? Or is there any other way of doing it?

My HTML button code lines are mentioned below:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">
    Submit
</button>
<button type="reset" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning">
    Reset
</button>
```

Thanks

AB

Comment: are you using it inside "row" "col" classes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately there aren't a 'class' of bootstrap to apply this 'effect'. The only thing you can do, is using @media on CSS. You can use it:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .btn, .btn-group {
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

You can apply one of the 'col' classes on the button, but the 'box' of the button will not follow the size of it content.

I hope it can help you. :)

Comment: Please don't do this to generic classes; making something full width is for visual appeal, whereas there are occasions where this rule will break the layout of a form or dropdown. Anywhere that you don't want this rule, you now have to opt out -- how? by adding another class or rule. It's just as trivial to create a single class and apply it where you want this effect.

Answer (score 11):

Create this new CSS class:

```
@media(max-width: 768px) {
    button.full-width {
        width: 100%;  
    }
}
```

And then apply it to your buttons:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success full-width">
    Submit
</button>
<button type="reset" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning full-width">
    Reset
</button>
```

In my opinion, it is a better idea than editing Bootstrap classes as [Claudio B](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39452032/4927984) suggested.

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask you one additional question though? Why is operation on self-made classes considered better design than operation done on predefined classes?

Comment: Edit the classes defined by Bootstrap is likely to affect the proper functioning of Bootstrap: If you do this ALL the buttons of your app will be affected.

In your case it is a small change, but if your app grows you will not have effective control over the changes.

Create a class specifically for this (as I suggested) is cleaner and does not require modification of Bootstrap's CSS.

Comment: I would point out that it is a general suggestion, which does not only apply to this case. I recommend to not directly edit Bootstrap files, when it can be avoided :-)

Answer (score 10):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">Submit</button> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Use the grid system

Answer (score 2):

Add **form-control** class

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success form-control">
    Submit 
</button>
<button type="reset" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning form-control">
    Reset
</button>
```

Comment: Unfortunately `form-control` makes makes the button take 100% of the width at all times and not just on small screens.